# @jsonbackreference doesn't bind relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I have two classes:

Person.java:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="owner_id")
public class Person extends Owner {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_sharing_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private CarSharing carSharing;
}
```

CarSharing.java:

```
@Entity
public class CarSharing extends MetadataEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Person owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carSharing", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private Set<Person> members;
}
```

I am using `@JsonBackReference` to avoid infinite cycles. The `CarSharing` class is working fine the problem only happens to the `Person` class.

Getting the person seems to ignore the `carSharing` property. As it is `null` when coming back to the server the update is unlinking the reference to the `carsharing_id` in the `person` table.

Stopping the loop is fine but i would also need the `carSharing` available in the `Person` class.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jackson 2.x, you can use the Annotation `@JsonIdentityInfo`:

> Whether Object Identity information is to be used for determining how to serialize/deserialize property value to/from JSON (and other data formats) will be based on existence (or lack thereof) of @JsonIdentityInfo annotation. 
> *see: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity*

For example, if you annotate the class `CarSharing`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
//...
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class CarSharing {
```

the JSON result of a person (I added a field name to this class) is:

```json
  {
    "carSharing": {
      "@id": 1,
      "id": 12345,
      "owner": {
        "carSharing": 1,
        "name": "owner"
      },
      "members": [
        {
          "carSharing": 1,
          "name": "owner"
        },
        {
          "carSharing": 1,
          "name": "driver2"
        },
        {
          "carSharing": 1,
          "name": "driver"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "driver2"
  }
```

And a CarSharing instance with `id=12345`:

```json
  {
    "@id": 1,
    "id": 12345,
    "owner": {
      "carSharing": 1,
      "name": "owner"
    },
    "members": [
      {
        "carSharing": 1,
        "name": "owner"
      },
      {
        "carSharing": 1,
        "name": "driver2"
      },
      {
        "carSharing": 1,
        "name": "driver"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The field `@id` is generated from jackson. If the referenced object is not serialized, the value is set to the `@id` of the referenced object.